# JQuery - find child div inside an item (also a div) within an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get a child div by ID from within an item of an array, which also happens to be a div. The reason that I want to do this is that I want to edit the child divs' style attribute programatically. Also, there will be multiple rows and that is why I have an array.

Say I have the following HTML.

```
<div class="row fileCompareTreeRow">
  <div class="col-xs-8"> </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4" id="progressBarDiv">
    <div ng-if="(node.pass != null)" class="pull-right">
        <div id="progressBarText"></div>
        <div id="progressbarCont"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to find the div with id "progressBarDiv". The following is the JavaScript code I have written to try to get this to work.

```
var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("fileCompareTreeRow");
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
  var row = rows[i];
  var rowHeight = $(row).height();
  if(rowHeight > 20){
    var div =  $(row).find("div#progressBarDiv");
    div.style.margin = "0 auto";
    div.style.padding = "10px";
  }
}
```

I keep getting an error, which states that I cannot change the margin attribute of 'undefined'. Meaning that the div is not being found. I've tried looking this up and tried going around it in different ways but I couldn't manage. Can someone help me please? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You just need to use querySelector as mentioned in my answer. Just a one word change to make things work.

Answer (score 2):

Just select `$("#progressBarDiv")`. ID must be unique across the DOM, so this will necessarily give the desired element.

Then use jQuery's methods, not vanilla JS ones (you're dealing with jQuery objects here) : `$("#progressBarDiv").css("padding", "10px")`.

This being said, I could see `ng-if`, meaning you're using Angular... and jQuery at the same time. (And also vanilla JS selectors like `document.getElementsByClassName`...) This is bad. This is really bad. Use Angular and do things the Angular way, *OR* use jQuery and do things the jQuery way, but not both.

Comment: only issue with this is that since the rows are generated on-the-fly, there will be multiple divs with the ID 'progressBarDiv' in the full page. However, each one of them is 'unique' to that row in a sense and I would only want to edit the div in that specific row. Should I use 'class' instead of 'id' since there are multiple items "progressBarDiv"s?

Comment: Well that's wrong. 1) An ID MUST be unique. Not in a row, unique in the full document. 2) As I said, use Angular OR jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't know that mixing Angular with JQuery or JS is bad. Beginner's mistake I guess.

Comment: You can make use of pure javascript which works great with Angular

Comment: Well they have completely different philosophies. jQuery manipulates the DOM, whereas Angular _generates_ the DOM on the fly from JS data. So what you're doing here is generating a wrong DOM with Angular, then trying to make it right by manipulating it with jQuery... Besides, you load two libraries, increasing your site's weight and complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can you .css() or .addclass()

```
$(row).find("div#progressBarDiv").css('margin','0 auto');
$(row).find("div#progressBarDiv").css('padding','10px');
```

Or

```
.progressBarDivCSS
{
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 10p;
}

$(row).find("div#progressBarDiv").addClass('progressBarDivCSS');
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! However I do have one question to ask. I'm guessing my code didn't work because I mixed JQuery objects with JS methods, right?

Comment: It failed because you were trying to use native JS to set the style of the collection returned by $.find, not the row object itself (one of the elements in the collection).  Using the jQuery .css method applies the style to every object in the collection.

Comment: Yeah, you tried to apply styles using js for the DOM returned by Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery [.css()](https://api.jquery.com/css/): see below snippet :

```js
var rows = $(".fileCompareTreeRow");
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
  var row = rows[i];
  var rowHeight = $(row).height();
  if(rowHeight > 20){
    var div1 =  $(row).find("div#progressBarDiv");
    console.log(div1)
    $(div1).css("margin","0 auto");
    $(div1).css("padding", "10px");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row fileCompareTreeRow">
  <div class="col-xs-8"> </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4" id="progressBarDiv">
    <div ng-if="(node.pass != null)" class="pull-right">
        <div id="progressBarText">s</div>
        <div id="progressbarCont">s</div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row fileCompareTreeRow">
  <div class="col-xs-8"> </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4" id="progressBarDiv">
    <div ng-if="(node.pass != null)" class="pull-right">
        <div id="progressBarText">s</div>
        <div id="progressbarCont">s</div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Or simply use the follwing Jquery code that applies style to all your targeted div

```js
$(".fileCompareTreeRow").find("div#progressBarDiv").css({"margin":"0 auto","padding":"10px"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row fileCompareTreeRow">
  <div class="col-xs-8"> </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4" id="progressBarDiv">
    <div ng-if="(node.pass != null)" class="pull-right">
        <div id="progressBarText">s</div>
        <div id="progressbarCont">s</div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row fileCompareTreeRow">
  <div class="col-xs-8"> </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4" id="progressBarDiv">
    <div ng-if="(node.pass != null)" class="pull-right">
        <div id="progressBarText">s</div>
        <div id="progressbarCont">s</div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way i find to solve this is by using pure JavaScript. We can use `querySelector` for this to get the `child` element `within` the parent. The code will be

```
var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("fileCompareTreeRow");
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
  var row = rows[i];
  var rowHeight = $(row).height();
  if(rowHeight > 20){
    var div =  row.querySelector('#progressBarDiv');
    div.style.margin = "0 auto";
    div.style.padding = "10px";
  }
}
```

The `querySelector` will look element within the element that is contained by the variable `row` and you will not get any error like `the margin attribute of 'undefined'`

For your simplicity here is the working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uq6qr9j3/1/)